# WPF textbox not losing focus when selecting custom control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox, custom-controls, lost-focus

In a WPF/MVVM application I have a custom control on a particular view. This control extends WPF DataGrid and contains User names and ids.
On the same view  I have some textboxes whose Text properties are bound to all different properties of User object exposed by the viewmodel and UpdateSourceTrigger for the Text properties are set to LostFocus.
Data gets updated as they should be whenever I leave a textbox (since the textbox looses focus). But problem is, this doesn't occur when I select any item in the custom control leaving any textbox, textbox data doesn't update. Can anyone explain what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your custom control has its own focus scope defined, thus allowing logical focus to be in both the text box and your custom control? Try checking in snoop.

Comment: Thanks Kent. Very helpful hint, and i've just found Focusable="False" within the ControlTemplate of the custom control. Does it mean that since the UserControl is not getting focus beacause of Focusable="False", the textbox still retaining its focus?

Comment: @Nero: that's quite possible, although it could have another focusable control within it. Snoop can tell you what control has focus too (see the status bar).